# Requirements for Instagram Graph API testing and development

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, prototyping

I'm trying to build a prototype which collects and analyses comments from Instagram. This can seemingly only be done with the Instagram Graph API. So to prototype and test I need:

- A business IG account connected to a Facebook account (the account to access and read the comments of)
- A Facebook App configured to access IG accounts (the account/app which gets authenticated to access the IG account)

However, this App needs to go through a verification process for each of the permissions required. The process apparently takes up to 5 days and needs a Privacy Policy on a website (neither of which I have yet).

This is a lot to do considering it is just a prototype/PoC to establish feasability and get better acquainted with using/testing the API and data.

Does anyone with experience working with the Instagram Graph API know whether I am over-thinking or misread what is required here? Or do you have to go through this before being able to access IG account comments?

Comment: As long as your app is in dev mode, you should still be able to ask your own developer account for all the necessary permissions, before you submit for review. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test

Comment: Thank you @CBroe - the app I'd created was a business one (which has no App mode). I'm guessing that I will be able to access my IG account (a business account) already associated with my Facebook account?

Comment: No. It's not as long as you think and it's pretty simple. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/discover-insights-from-your-instagram-business-account-with-facebook-graph-api-and-python-81d20ee2e751) article will work.

Comment: Thank you, @Clegane. I haven't touched Python in years but that looks a good reason to get back in.